# HTML markup breaking razor using

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Default", new { controller = "Home", action = "Form" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @ID="FormId", @Name="FormId"}))
{
    <span>...</span>
    <div class="clearFloats"><!-- ---></div>
    <span>...</span>
}
```

And since moving to Razor 2, MVC 4 I now get the error:

- > The using block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you
  >   have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this
  >   block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as
  >   markup.

If I remove the `<div class="clearFloats"><!-- ---></div>` code, everything is OK. I know the solution is to change these float clearing divs for a different construct of somesort, but why is it now breaking?

Comment: Is it happening only in MVC4 ? worked fine in MVC3

Comment: Looks like a bug in WebPages v2 to me.

Comment: What is the content of those spans? Can't see why that would matter given what you said fixes the issue but it possibly contributes..

Comment: @Shyju Yup, it compiled fine in MVC3

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It varies from page to page (TBH, mostly no spans... That was the simplest breaking example I could come up with to illustrate the query).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary solution would be to wrap the `<!-- -->` with `@Html.Raw("<!-- -->")` which seems to eliminate the error.

**Edit**: Actually the problem in your example is is the trailing three dashes `--->` on the close comment tag. Remove one of those and it works correctly.